# Load data into tableview form cells

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a program where a `UITableView` contains custom cells loaded from nibs. These cells have textfields and a `UIImage`. I've been passing the information they contain to a custom class and encoding/decoding the class for data persistence. When I want to load the data, I put the information from the class into the cell. This works fine for 1 cell, but not for more than one. I've checked, and the classes are being written to file correctly.

This is my retrieval method:

```
//Fills an array if the file exists, otherwise returns nil
- (NSMutableArray*) findFile: (NSString *) add
{
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[self saveFilePath:add]])
    {
        NSString *temp = [add stringByAppendingString:@"dat"];
        namesIndexer = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[self saveFilePath:temp]];

        if (namesIndexer == nil) return nil;

        NSMutableArray *thing = [NSMutableArray new];
        for (NSString *place in namesIndexer)
        {
            temp = [add stringByAppendingString:place];
            PTextHolder *p = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:[self saveFilePath:temp]];
            [thing addObject:p];
        }
        return thing;
    }
    else 
    {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Note that this is in a different class, and it calls the method from the holder.

```
//Returns a cell to be used at a row, populates it from the holder object
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
    static NSString *personCellId = @"personID";
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"PersonCell" bundle:nil];
    [tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:personCellId];
    PersonCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:personCellId];

    cell.owner = tableView;
    if (mineTable == nil) mineTable = tableView;
    cell.delegated = formDataStorage;

    [formDataStorage putWhatShouldBeInThisCellForThisRowInIt:cell:(int*)indexPath.row];

    cell.currentRow = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Here's the method it calls:

```
- (void) putWhatShouldBeInThisCellForThisRowInIt: (PersonCell *) someCell: (int *) someRow
{
    if ((NSUInteger) someRow >= cake.count)
    {
        NSLog(@"The cake has been undercooked");
        return;
    }

    PTextHolder *temp = [cake objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger) someRow];

    someCell.firstName.text = temp.first;
    someCell.lastName.text = temp.last;
    someCell.middleName.text = temp.middle;
    someCell.suffixName.text = temp.suffix;
    someCell.email.text = temp.email;
    someCell.theSignature.image = temp.sig;
}
```

Anything look wrong here/would cause only one cell to be loaded?

Comment: can you add code for cellForRow method as well.

Comment: after reading from file, print your array to the console to check if it is valid. if array is valid, you should check your cellForRowAtIndexPath: method. you can post it here

Comment: @Morion, the array only has one object in it after it is populated from file load.

Comment: print it's description to console to find out what is this object

Comment: I put a breakpoint in, and the object is the correct object with the data in it. The problem is, there are supposed to be multiple objects in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check first the number of items in the array with

> [array count]

, if the number of items is equal to 1, then the problem is as you guessed with the encoding/decoding.

If not, your code is right and the problem is with your code to load the cells.

By the way, why dont you store your array of "cellInfoClass" directly using:

> [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:array toFile:filePath]

and retrieve directly the array.

I guess you already added the encoding/coding code to your class, if not is like that:

```
/**  
 * Returns an object initialized from data in a given unarchiver. (required)  
 *  
 * @param decoder: An unarchiver object.  
 */
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    if (self = [super init]) {      
    // If parent class also adopts NSCoding, replace [super init]
    // with [super initWithCoder:decoder] to properly initialize.       
       [self setName:[coder decodeObjectForKey:@"name"]];       
       [self setId:[coder decodeIntForKey:@"id"]];      
       [self setDomain:[coder decodeObjectForKey:@"domain"]];   
    }
    return self;     
 }


/**  
 * Encodes the receiver using a given archiver. (required) 
 * @param coder: An archiver object.  
 */
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder{
    // If parent class also adopts NSCoding, include a call to
    // [super encodeWithCoder:encoder] as the first statement.  
    [coder encodeObject:name forKey:@"name"];
    [coder encodeInt:id forKey:@"id"];
    [coder encodeObject:domain forKey:@"domain"];
}
```

Comment: There is only 1 item in the array, and I am actually using archiveRootObject, just in a different method (this project is ~15 kloc, so I haven't included all the code from all the files). I'm using the same code you posted for encoding/decoding, and it works for one object, so I am confused as to why it doesn't work for the others.

Comment: Although I am archiving the individual files, not the array itself. The array just stores the names of the files. I unarchive the names array and then use it to find the locations of all the other files.

Comment: If there is only 1 item, then the cellForRowAtIndexPath: method will be called once, you need to first, identify why is only loading 1 name. Have you validated if before you write the array into disk have more than 1 item? maybe you are creating/replacing a new array each time with only 1 item.

Comment: It turns out that my save file path was somehow getting changed every iteration of the save loop. This answer got me on the right track, so I'm marking it correct.